# How do I set a computed NSManagedObject property automatically before it is saved?

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject

Say I have an `NSManagedObject` subclass called `Item`. Whenever an `item` instance is saved I want to update a property based on a computed value from a transient property. I know I can update the property whenever the transient property changes but for this question, assume there's a good reason I don't want to do that.

I tried to do this in the `willSave` method as follows:

```
- (void)willSave
{
    self.computedProperty = [self computedValueFromTransientProperty];
}
```

This causes a crash when saving the context. If I move the code out of `willSave` and set the property explicitly before invoking save it works fine. The apple docs say you should avoid changing managed object properties in `willSave`.

QUESTION: is there a good way to build functionality into a `NSManagedObject` subclass so a property can be updated just before save w/o having to explicitly set the property from outside the class and w/o setting the property every time the transient property changes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're able to set persistent properties from `willSave`, you just have to be more careful about it.

From the `willSave` docs:

> This method can have “side effects” on persistent values. You can use
>   it to, for example, compute persistent values from other transient or
>   scratchpad values.
>
> If you want to update a persistent property value, you should
>   typically test for equality of any new value with the existing value
>   before making a change. If you change property values using standard
>   accessor methods, Core Data will observe the resultant change
>   notification and so invoke willSave again before saving the object’s
>   managed object context. If you continue to modify a value in willSave,
>   willSave will continue to be called until your program crashes.

So, what's happening is you're changing `computedProperty`, which is causing `willSave` to be called again, which changes `computedProperty` which calls `willSave` again, until your program crashes.

To fix this you need to check whether or not `computedProperty` needs to be set again:

```
- (void)willSave
{
    id computed = [self computedValueFromTransientProperty];
    if (![self.computedProperty isEqual:computed])
    {
        self.computedProperty = computed;
    }
}
```

This will mean that `computedValueFromTransientProperty` will get called twice, so you might not want to do this if the method is computationally expensive.

Another option is to use the primitive set method which will mean `willSave` won't get called twice, but might have side affects depending on how your app interacts with Core Data:

```
- (void)willSave
{
    self.primitiveComputedProperty = [self computedValueFromTransientProperty];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I did see that in the docs but wasn't thinking straight. I used your first suggestion but to eliminate the double computation added an iVar that is initialized to nil and set to nil in `didSave`. In `willSave`, if this iVar is nil I set it to the computed value. I then use the logic above comparing this iVar to the persistant property. Works great and I only do the expensive computation once. Thanks!

Comment: There is an issue with this approach in that willSave is not called unless the ManagedObject is flagged as dirty. Setting a transient property can flag the object dirty - but mutating it wont.